# Install python module hosted on a external url

Tags: python, pip, python-module

I have a few modules hosted on a external website : https://example.com/packages

I am attempting to install a module by running the following `pip install` command, however, it defaults to `https://pypi.org/....`

```
pip install ext-package==1.1.0 --extra-index-url https://example.com/packages



Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/ext-package/
```

How do I force it to look for modules hosted on a external url?

Comment: Why can't you make your packages available on pypi?

Comment: It's not my package. and it's pre-release, will probably be hosted on PyPi eventually.

Comment: You still can (if you have access to the whole code)...if for instance a license is included that states you can redistribute it non-commercially. Attribution would undoubtedly be required though.

Comment: Yeah. For now, I am trying to figuring out how to install it from the site it is currently hosted on.

Comment: first download the package and open it into a terminal / cmd and run the setup file to install using command: python setup.py install